# How can I use Fluent without modifying the first variable

Tags: php, laravel

Let's say I have a pretty simple table and somewhere in my Laravel installation I put:

`$model = DB::connection('second')->table('models');`

Later on I wanna do something like:

`echo $model->where('column', 1)->count();`

and

`echo $model->where('another_column', 0)->count();`

Yet the second will not work, because `$model` is already something else. It has to do something with that chaining, but how can I do the same thing without altering `$model`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try using PHP's `clone`:

```
$baseQuery = DB::connection('second')->table('models');

$countQuery = clone $baseQuery;
$countQuery->where('column', 1)->count();

$otherQuery = clone $baseQuery;
$otherQuery->where('another_column', 0)->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you were to do `$model = $model->where('another_column', 0)->count();` the second will work.

Then of course if you don't want to alter `$model` you can do `$modelb = $model->where('another_column', 0)->count();`.